# Passing ifstream to a function in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to build 16 different suffix trees for a gene sequencing project. They're being built in main as such

```
int main()
{  
  ifstream fp;  
  fp.open("filepath", ifstream::in);  
  Tree I(fp);  
  fp.close();
```

I'm attempting to use them in my constructor with this code:

```
Tree::Tree(ifstream &fp)   
{  
  string current = "";  
  char* line;  
  fp.getLine(line, 100); //ignore first line  
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++)     
    {  
      char temp = (char)fp.get();  
      if(temp=='\n')i--;  
      else current+=temp;  
    }  
  insert(current);  
  while(fp.good())  
    {  
      current = current.substr(1,99);  
      char temp = (char)fp.get();  
      if(temp=='\n')temp=(char)fp.get();  
      if(temp==EOF) break;  
      current+=temp;  
      insert(current);  
    }  
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I get these errors for every instance in which I use fp:

> suffix.cpp: In constructor `Tree::Tree(std::ifstream&)`:
>   suffix.cpp:12: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iosfwd:89: error: declaration of `struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`
>   suffix.cpp:15: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/iosfwd:89: error: declaration of `struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`

Answer (score 7):

Have you #included the `fstream` header?

Comment: +1. `std::basic_ifstream` was forward declared in `<iosfwd>`, but `<fstream>` isn't actually included in the source file where the code is located.

Comment: I'd included it in my main, but not in the file with the offending function. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have #included <iosfwd> instead of <fstream> in your source files.